# Handle unknown types without casting

Tags: c#, generics, architecture

I've been trying to find an elegant solution for a recurring problem in a small library I'm writing in C#.

Here is a breakdown of the problem.

```
// IMPLEMENTATION

public class MyArgs : Args {}

public class MyItem : Item
{
    public override void Run(Args args)
    {
        // CAN I AVOID THIS CAST?
        var myArgs = args as MyArgs;
    }
}


// LIBRARY

public class Args {}

public abstract class Item
{
    public abstract void Run(Args args);
}

public class Manager
{
    public List<Item> items;

    public void RunAll (Args args)
    {
        foreach (Item item in items)
        {
            item.Run(args);
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, I would like to be able to send the MyArgs to MyItem through the manager, without it knowing about it. MyArgs is something defined by the user, so I will only know it's base class.

I've tried some solutions with generics like, that will solve the problem:

```
public abstract class Item<T>
{
    public abstract void Run(T args);
}
```

But I would like to avoid making the Manager generic.

So I guess my question is if there are any tricks I can use in order to get around this, or if I'm simply trying to do something that's impossible.

Comment: Making `Item` class generic doesn't force you to make `Manager` class generic one. `RunAll` method works with `Args` type anyway. Why do you need a specific `MyArgs` in this case? How would you like to choose a specific `Item` to work with specific args?

Comment: Also why **do** you cast? Depending on what you´re doing within `Run`you can safely use `args` directly without any cast at all. Indeed generics won´t help you much, because they rely on **compile-time*-type-inference. However you provide the actual types only at **runtime**.